# send image file as message in biztalk server 2006

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk2006r2

I have a image file with extention.tif

I have set ports for sending and receiving file.

I have configured sending port to a folder and receiving port to a folder.

My sending folder's name is send1 and receiving folder's name is receive1.

Now i want to do that whenever any image file falls in receive1 folder it should automatically transfer to send1 folder.

How can i do this in biztalk server?

Comment: Has the answer below solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this;
a) Set your pipeline on the receive port to "PassThruReceive" and send port to PassThruTransmit, then any file dropped in the the receive location is sent as-is to the send location.

b)Set a **Filter** on the send port to be the receive port name. This tells the send port to subscribe to messages published by your receive port, like;

```
 BTS.ReceivePortName=<yourreceiveportname>
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by teepeeboy will work in your case, here is a more detailed step by step instruction on how to do it http://bryantlikes.com/HelloBizTalkFileTransfer.aspx The screen resemebles BizTalk 2004, but the concepts are still the same.

One additional thing, on Send port set the file name property to %MessageID%.tif instead of the default .xml